# Game Development in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been using Surfaceview For simple 2d racing car Development, as I come to know that using holder on canvas whole surface is redrawing, I want to redraw only car as physical position changed rather than lane, how to redraw only single component?

Answer (score 0):

You could use bools within your onDraw. Within your onDraw you have a check such as

```
if(carMoved == false)
{
    // draw everything
}
else
{
    // draw your car
    carMoved = false; // this resets your onDraw so your whole canvas is re-drawn next time you invalidate()
}
```

There are proabably a lot of different ways that you can do it, however I feel this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't redraw more than just the car, it's not going to look right. At the *very least*, you have to also draw over where the car was in the last frame. Otherwise it will show in both positions.

From [the developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#on-surfaceview):

> Note: On each pass you retrieve the Canvas from the SurfaceHolder, the previous state of the Canvas will be retained. In order to properly animate your graphics, you must re-paint the entire surface. For example, you can clear the previous state of the Canvas by filling in a color with drawColor() or setting a background image with drawBitmap(). Otherwise, you will see traces of the drawings you previously performed.